# How to embed an Argo Workflows widget into a webpage?

Tags: web-frontend, argo-workflows

How do I embed an Argo Workflows UI **widget** into a web page?

Are there code examples (and a gallery of widgets) available somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Argo Workflows UI features *widgets* for embedding into other applications. The [widget documentation](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/widgets/) explains they are intended to be embedded using HTML *iframe* tags, although the docs do not (currently) provide any examples.

The widgets are components of Argo Workflows UI written using React. There is also a gallery of the available widgets for any given workflow (see [source](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/2a5c4e8d2c983b88044c84e90e0aa5805edfe5b2/ui/src/app/widgets/widget-gallery.tsx) in GitHub). To see this gallery rendered, navigate to a particular workflow in the Argo Workflows UI and click "share". (Viewing the source of the rendered gallery web page will provide an example of the HTML needed to insert the widget in another application.)

Note the widgets in the gallery may fail to display, with a "refused to connect" message. In this case, you can still click "Preview" to view each widget directly (without the surrounding page). The failure occurs because Argo Workflows UI may default to serving the URL for the embeddable widget with the header `X-Frame-Options: DENY` (which instructs the web client not to display the contents inside another page). This can be rectified by launching the server with different arguments.